# How to allow REST API calls from localhost or 127.0.0.1?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento2.3

We are trying to develop an application (in Angular) to make REST API calls to Magento. How can we modify Magento's ".htaccess" to allow calls from `http://localhost:4200` or `http:\\127.0.0.1` ? This will help us a lot in development.

Our test magento store is at http://www.ngstrorefront.com/magento

Works: Calling this `http://www.ngstrorefront.com/magento/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=5` directly from POSTMAN (with conten-type and authorization headers)

Works: Angular application http://www.ngstrorefront.com/core/products (works.. can fetch data from Magento running on the same domain)

Fail: When we run the Angular application from localhost making calls to `http://www.ngstrorefront.com/magento/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=5` we see CORS errors.

Comment: Install (Allow-Control-Allow-Origin) extension to your browser and check